# indexes of multiple occurences in string

Tags: c#, string

I need help with this part of my code.
I'm checking the occurences of char within a string:

```
public string Obsahuje(string slovo, char pismeno)
{
    if (slovo.Contains(pismeno))
    {
        char[] array = uhodnute.ToCharArray();
        int index;
        int zacatek = 0;
        do
        {
            index = slovo.IndexOf(pismeno, zacatek);
            array[index] = pismeno;
            zacatek = index;
        } while (slovo.IndexOf(pismeno, zacatek + 1) != -1);

        uhodnute = new string(array);

        return uhodnute;
    }
    --zivot;
    return uhodnute;
}
```

It works fine with character that occurs just once, but when I try another that occurs twice or more times, the program just freezes. No error, it just stops responding. I know it's probably something very stupid, but I'm doing this for so long that I just can't see it. I'd appreciate some help.

Edit: It works with:

```
do
  {
   index = slovo.IndexOf(pismeno, index);
   array[index] = pismeno;
    index++;
   } while (slovo.IndexOf(pismeno, index) != -1);
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through in the debugger?

Comment: Suppose the first character matches. index  = 0. So next time around the loop it starts looking from index ... zero (provided there is a second occurrence somewhere).

Comment: Where does `uhodnute` come from?

Comment: "uhodnute" is a variable within class, that part works fine. And I added that +1 to avoid getting the same index over and over. Or is that wrong?

Comment: OK so you want to basically put the character `pismeno` into `uhodnute` at the indexes where it shows up in `slovo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't update the value of `index`, and the code freezes because it remains in the while loop for ever.

```
int index;

int zacatek = 0;
    do
    {
        index = slovo.IndexOf(pismeno, zacatek);
        array[index] = pismeno;
        index++;
        zacatek = index;
    } while (slovo.IndexOf(pismeno, zacatek + 1) != -1);
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked, thanks :) I made some other changes, but I didn't think of that.